# Upgrading to Windows 8.1 causes window.attachEvent("onload", to fail

Tags: attachevent

I have a program that I use to develop web applications called CodeCharge Studio. I have just upgraded to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8 and I now keep getting an error when using the program. The error occurs in a common javascript file and the line is window.attachEvent("onload", CommonOnLoad);

Does anyone know if this event has changed by installing 8.1 or perhaps it is the update to IE11.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same error and I can't use CCS 5 anymore. There's a thread here: http://forums.codecharge.com/posts.php?post_id=122027 Right now, I'm installing VirtualBox with Windows 7 :(

Comment: Now that is two users with the same hassle. I certainly hope that Yessofware will look at this soonest!

Comment: CCS worked perfectly with ver. 8.0 but 8.1 breaks CCS.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Windows 8.0 used IE10 (which used 'attachEvent') and Windows 8.1 uses IE11.

According to Microsoft [Internet Explorer Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), IE11 is deprecating the attachEvent that CCS5 generates:

"attachEvent is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use addEventListener. For info, see Compatibility changes."

Looks like `addEventListener` is the DOM 3 standards approach which IE 11 is moving towards.

As 'Internet Explorer 5.5 or higher' is a system requirement, I'm assuming that CCS uses some parts of Internet Explorer when it's generating and the code being created is using the 'old' IE styles.

The thread above in the yessoftware forums mention the CCS5 Team are currently working on an update for Windows 8.1 problems (as at 25 Oct 2013)

**UPDATED**: 30 Oct - update CCS 5.1.1.18990 available, including Win 8.1 fix  (http://support.yessoftware.com/updates.asp)